# Not able to Extract Jar file from Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jar

After Running the Project as Maven build(mvn clean compile install).In Eclipse while trying to export the project as Jar File with the below steps.

Export->JAR File->Export generated class files and resources ->Export class files with compiler errors & Warnings

I am getting the following error

```
> JAR creation failed. See details for additional information.   Class
> files on classpath not found or not accessible for:
> 'VeryOldccstore/src/test/java/com/oracle/cloud/commerce/test/AdminAbstract.java'
> Exported with compile warnings:
> VeryOldccstore/src/test/java/com/oracle/cloud/commerce/test/AdminOrderTest.java
> Class files on classpath not found or not accessible for:
> 'VeryOldccstore/src/test/java/com/oracle/cloud/commerce/test/AdminOrderTest.java'
> Class files on classpath not found or not accessible for:
> 'VeryOldccstore/src/test/java/com/oracle/cloud/commerce/test/AdminInventoryTest.java'
> Problem writing VeryOldccstore/src/main/java/com/.svn/all-wcprops to
> JAR: duplicate entry: com/.svn/all-wcprops   duplicate entry:
> com/.svn/all-wcprops   Problem writing
> VeryOldccstore/src/main/java/com/.svn/entries to JAR: duplicate entry:
> com/.svn/entries   duplicate entry: com/.svn/entries   Problem writing
> VeryOldccstore/src/main/java/com/oracle/.svn/all-wcprops to JAR:
> duplicate entry: com/oracle/.svn/all-wcprops   duplicate entry:
> com/oracle/.svn/all-wcprops   Problem writing
> VeryOldccstore/src/main/java/com/oracle/.svn/entries to JAR: duplicate
> entry: com/oracle/.svn/entries   duplicate entry:
> com/oracle/.svn/entries   Problem writing
> VeryOldccstore/src/main/java/com/oracle/cloud/.svn/all-wcprops to JAR:
> duplicate entry: com/oracle/cloud/.svn/all-wcprops   duplicate entry:
> com/oracle/cloud/.svn/all-wcprops   Problem writing
> VeryOldccstore/src/main/java/com/oracle/cloud/.svn/entries to JAR:
> duplicate entry: com/oracle/cloud/.svn/entries   duplicate entry:
> com/oracle/cloud/.svn/entries   Exported with compile warnings:
> VeryOldccstore/src/main/java/com/oracle/cloud/commerce/CCClient.java  
> Exported with compile warnings:
> VeryOldccstore/src/main/java/com/oracle/cloud/commerce/CCClientUtils.java
> Problem writing
> VeryOldccstore/src/main/java/com/oracle/cloud/commerce/.svn/all-wcprops
> to JAR: duplicate entry: com/oracle/cloud/commerce/.svn/all-wcprops  
> duplicate entry: com/oracle/cloud/commerce/.svn/all-wcprops   Problem
> writing
> VeryOldccstore/src/main/java/com/oracle/cloud/commerce/.svn/entries to
> JAR: duplicate entry: com/oracle/cloud/commerce/.svn/entries  
> duplicate entry: com/oracle/cloud/commerce/.svn/entries   Exported
> with compile warnings:
> VeryOldccstore/src/main/java/com/oracle/cloud/commerce/model/inventory/SkuInventory.java
> Exported with compile warnings:
> VeryOldccstore/src/main/java/com/oracle/cloud/commerce/model/order/PriceDetails.java
> Exported with compile warnings:
> VeryOldccstore/src/main/java/com/oracle/cloud/commerce/model/order/CommerceItem.java
> Exported with compile warnings:
> VeryOldccstore/src/main/java/com/oracle/cloud/commerce/services/AdminOrderService.java
> Problem writing VeryOldccstore/src/main/java/.svn/all-wcprops to JAR:
> duplicate entry: .svn/all-wcprops   duplicate entry: .svn/all-wcprops 
> Problem writing VeryOldccstore/src/main/java/.svn/entries to JAR:
> duplicate entry: .svn/entries   duplicate entry: .svn/entries
```

But Jar file is generated in target folder succesfully .I am not sure reason for this error

Comment: The process should ignore the .svn folders which it is not. It still generates the jar so it looks like you are fine

Comment: @DavidBrossard jar gets created when compiling as Maven build.But i have problem while trying to Export as Jar.Not sure why its happening

Comment: I think it happens because Maven is smart enough to ignore stuff under `.svn` directory as there is no `*.java` files there. But Eclipse is not that smart and tries to pack everything in jar

Comment: @Ivan what could be the best solution for it,just to make use of the jar file from target Folder ?

Comment: Depending on what you need. There are 3 options: use jar from target folder build by Maven, configure Eclipse to ignore `.svn` and everything inside it, use Maven to deploy jar to binary repository and get jar from there.